# Code Coverage shows 0% for IntelliJ while running web app

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I have a web server application that I am running inside IntelliJ. I want to run the server with code coverage, then execute an external test harness that will make requests, and see how much of the code is executed by those requests.

I can generate the correct code coverage when running unit tests from within the IDE, but when I run with Code Coverage on and execute with an external harness, I get all 0's for code coverage.

If I run the web app in the debugger instead, it triggers breakpoints as expected, so I know that code is being executed.

Please help!

Comment: Does the server close/shutdown at the end? Perhaps it needs the server to close before generating the results - I know some other tools for other platforms require that.

Comment: It does, but I know that's not the issue - when I kill a set of unit tests in the middle of a run, the coverage comes through fine.

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue. Clicking Stop to end the process results in all 0% coverage, presumably due to the process not getting a chance to tidy up and generate results:

> Stop  Click this button to terminate the current process externally by means of the standard mechanisms.

Clicking Exit instead allows the coverage to generate properly:

> Exit  Click this button to terminate the current process gracefully using in-process internal mechanisms.

See here for more detail: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/test-runner-tab.html#

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out next week when I'm in the office.

Comment: Although why does it correctly generate when I hit stop in the middle of unit tests?

Answer (score 6):

This solution worked for me:

Go to IntelliJ Toolbar --> View --> ToolWindows --> Coverage.
A Window wil appear on the right side. Here you can delete Classes from the list by selecting them and hit the red X on the bottom left corner.

[image: screenshot of menu]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think  image of coverage window will give more clarity

Answer (score 1):

Got 0% coverage in ur IDEA?

Maybe you are viewing coverage per class. Try to switch it OFF using this little button:

[image]

Edit:

This button is supposed to show/switch coverage per test. It only appears, when you run your tests "with coverage" and it is located on toolbar of a Run panel (Alt + 4).

Comment: Most useless answer. I can't find that button and I don't even know what's supposed to mean / do.

Answer (score -1):

This is addition to answer given by Maurits will like add another image of coverage window. You just click 'X' red mark to close the coverage lines in left side.

[image]